# How i can set firmware environment variable in UEFI driver

Tags: c, windows, uefi

In a Windows application, I have a `GetFirmwareEnvironmentVariableA` function to read a firmware environment variable. Is there any way to write something in this variable in uefi driver and read from it later in Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function to set an NVRAM variable is called SetVariable() and is available to UEFI drivers via EFI_RUNTIME_SERVICES table.

To know more about it's interface and usage, read chapter 7.2 Variable Services of the [UEFI 2.6 specification](https://www.uefi.org/sites/default/files/resources/UEFI%20Spec%202_6.pdf).