# Setting NVRAM variable using WinAPI

Tags: winapi, uefi

I'm trying to setup my own NVRAM variable (nv+rt+bs) using WinAPI (SetFirmwareEnvironmentVariable). It fails with my variable and successfully completed with BootOrder. What do I do wrong? Is it possible to setup my own variable using WinAPI?

I'm trying to setup my variable using this code

```
void setMyNVRAM()
{
    // here I setup SE_SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_NAME privilege

    uint16_t value = 0x5aa5;

    if (!SetFirmwareEnvironmentVariable(L"MY_VARIABLE",
       L"{12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012}", &value, sizeof (value)))
    {
        std::cout << "error while settin up MY_VARIABLE. Error code: " 
                  << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "success" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

`SetFirmwareEnvironmentVariable` returns 0 and `GetLastError()` returns 5 (access denied). I also tried to write into `BootOrder` variable and it was successfully completed.

Comment: The documentation suggests that the error code is a mapping from an error being returned by the system firmware.  What happens if you try to create the same variable from the EFI shell?  Probably either the variable name or the namespace GUID is restricted to matching existing values.

Answer (score 0):

According to the instructions on the [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setfirmwareenvironmentvariableexa).

> To write a firmware environment variable, the user account that the
>   app is running under must have the SE_SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_NAME
>   privilege. A Universal Windows app must be run from an administrator
>   account and follow the requirements outlined in Access UEFI firmware
>   variables from a Universal Windows App.

[Customizing user privileges for an account in Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/119983/customizing-user-privileges-for-an-account-in-windows-xp-vista-7)

A similar discussion: [How i can set firmware environment variable in UEFI driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54557111/how-i-can-set-firmware-environment-variable-in-uefi-driver)

Comment: Thak you for answer. There is a comment in my code that says that I set SE_SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_NAME privilege. My app are run from an administrator account.
I try this code on another computer and it works pretty good. Maybe it's something like firmware protection. As soon as I find it out I'l write an answer.

There is one thing I didn't understand is how to add Capabilities tag to assembly manifest.